# Discord Embeds -Adjusting Thumbnail

Tags: embed, discord

So, in embeds you can set a thumbail, but unfortunately it is pretty small. Is there a way how to adjust the position and the size?

Code:

```
if (message.content === prefix + 'aot') {
   const embed = new RichEmbed()
     .setColor(0xFF0000)
     .setTitle("Attack on Titan")
     .setThumbnail("https://orig00.deviantart.net/f9ca/f/2013/145/9/b/shingeki_no_kyojin_render_v1_by_bryan1213-d66iwnc.png")
     .addField("Episodes:", "49")
     .addField("Genres:", "Action, Mystery, Drama")
     .addField("Story","Several hundred years ago, humans were nearly exterminated by titans. Titans are typically several stories tall, seem to have no intelligence, devour human beings and, worst of all, seem to do it for the pleasure rather than as a food source. A small percentage of humanity survived by walling themselves in a city protected by extremely high walls, even taller than the biggest of titans.")
     .setTimestamp();
     message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because discord is available on different types of devices such as smartphones they don't allow much customization when it comes to embeds. Images and text content of embeds is rendered to fit the client properly and cannot be specified by the sender.
Setting a thumbnail just means specifying a URL to an image, nothing beyond that is currently possible with the API.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setImage("https://placekitten.com/700/500")` instead.

[image: A screenshot showing the difference between .setThumbnail and .setImage]

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to do `embed.set_image(url=image_link)` (note the **`url=`** part).

Comment: @aheze Are you using Python? My answer was related to JavaScript using Discord.js. Still great it helped you.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'm using python... but `setImage`/`set_image` was exactly what I was looking for, thanks again